# what does radius property of euclideancolorfiltering exactly means?

Tags: c#, radius

I have been working on object tracking using euclideancolorfiltering and when I vary the radius using filter.radius property and keep on increasing its value,then it seems that the image colour is varying in an unpredicatable manner.I am not able to understand the mechanism that is happening with variation of this radius property.Any help regarding this would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/67fa83b5-dede-8d3a-8d3b-b7a6b9859538.htm, read *Remarks* section. It explains pretty much what it does in gross.

Answer (score 0):

It filters pixels, which color is inside/outside of RGB sphere with specified center and radius - it keeps pixels with colors inside/outside of the specified sphere and fills the rest with specified color.
The filter accepts 24 and 32 bpp color images for processing.

Comment: Thank you so much@Tigran,utility.I have been through the above mentioned section earlier.Though I could perceive what it does in overalI  but could not figure out the exact algorithm or mathematical formulation behind these image processing task.

Comment: Is there any specific term used for this?Can it be referred to as texture mapping?

Comment: I would be very grateful if anyone can help out regarding this.